# jpeg image won't load via <img> tag...png/gif working fine?

Tags: html, css, image, jpeg

I've been building a website for awhile now and I had all the images uploaded as pngs. After realizing that the images were taking too long to load I changed them all to jpegs but now none of them load on the website? Even if I just take this line of code and put the html file in the same folder as the image nothing comes up. I'm completely stumped? Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

```
<img src="placepublic.jpg" alt="Public Space" height="560" width="960">
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it `.jpg` or `.jpeg`? There is a difference...

Comment: have you tried `.jpeg` extension?

Comment: wow both comments 16 seconds ago!

Comment: I have tried both .jpeg and .jpg. Neither will work!

Comment: the image itself has a .jpg extension.

Comment: It may be `image.jgp.jpeg` or `image.jpg.jpg`. Chances are you are not seeing the actual extension.

Comment: Thank you! There was a bloody SPACE between the last letter and the extension name! God damn. Thanks for the help people!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
`<img src="placepublic.jpeg" alt="Public Space" height="560" width="960">`
```

allways check you image file extension, it allways be the same name and extention, dor you can load in the html file, and check the image is on the same level of your html  file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the capital letter for extension?

Try using:

```
<img src="placepublic.JPG" alt="Public Space" height="560" width="960">
```

or

```
<img src="placepublic.JPEG" alt="Public Space" height="560" width="960">
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a jpeg image file.(img.jpeg in my system)

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div><img src="img.jpg"/></div>                     
</div>
```

But i use .jpg extension in html it work for me. n image loaded too !!